# How can I override autoscroll=true on one page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an SPA and need the links to scroll to top when going from one route to another.

However, I want to disable that on one view as we are using a search that uses selects to update the route in the url to make the search result shareable.

```
Ex: $location.path($location.path()).search('state', $scope.myState);
```

If I don't do it this way, the page does not update with results.

With ng-view set to autoscroll=true, it updates the entire page once a select has been used.

`$anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();` 
Does not disable it at all for the one view/module.

`angular.module('projects').value('$anchorScroll', angular.noop);`
Disables it, but does it site wide. So if I go from projects to FAQ, it does not go to the top.

I could be doing this wrong with the location path and it have nothing to do with autoscroll as that seems to be working as documented.

Thanks, 
AngularN00b

UPDATE:
Seems like it could work, but I can't get it working at all:

In index.html

`<div ng-view class="content-wrapper" ng-class="{'secondary': !is_path('/')}" autoscroll="enableAutoScroll"></div>`

In Project controller:

`$scope.selectSubject = function() {
    $scope.enableAutoScroll = false;
    $location.path($location.path()).search('subject', $scope.mySubject);
  };`

I can see logs and its updating the value to false on the project page.

Answer (score 1):

The [ngView](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)'s `autoscroll` attribute accept an angular expression, so you could bind it with a `$scope`:

```
<div ng-view autoscroll="enableAutoScroll">
```

And before calling the `$location.path()`, you can enable/disable the auto scrolling like this:

```
$scope.enableAutoScroll = false;
```

Hope this helps.